# Xcode encountered an error in xcode 11.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I try to install the provisioning profile the Xcode give the below error "Xcode encountered an error"
(i try thing in updated provisioning profile, not in new profile)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked Console.app for error messages?

Comment: please describe your problem to give developers the ability to help you

Comment: @mooody i just download latest provisioning profile and try to install in Xcode nothings else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the bug in Xcode 11.2.1 I just logged in the accounts and download manual  profile (The screen open from the Xcode > Preferences > Accounts)

[image]

Comment: If anyone else needs: that is Xcode > Preferences > Accounts

Comment: yes right @VictorAlves this is a screen from : Xcode > Preferences > Accounts

Comment: Best solution : 
XCode > Windows > Devices and Simulators > Device tab > Right click on any device > Unpair device
Now install profiles and pair the device again.

Answer (score 2):

If Download manual profiles does not work for you then -

1) open the older version of Xcode then 
2) Add the provisioning profile. 
3) Now quit the older version of Xcode and open the new version and it is added!

Comment: yes its possible way.. but ideallly all people not keep 2 versions of xcode at a time

Comment: @MitulBhadeshiya that is true!

Answer (score 1):

you can manually import the profile -

project targets setting---> signing&Capabilities --> Provising Profile ---> import Profile

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest provisioning profile from apple developer console and choose import profile from Xcode, select the downloaded profile and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tired with several solutions and among those, it seems to me that the best solution is,

1. Go to
   XCode > Windows > Devices and Simulators > Device tab > Right click on any device > Unpair device
2. Unpair all the connected devices
3. Install the Provision profiles
4. Pair the devices again.

I guess this solution will work all the time.

[image]